# Questions about lyrics found in the song "As Long As You Love Me"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, lyrics

[Source.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7yBhaxJBE8)

> We don't need no wings to fly ([here](https://youtu.be/Y7yBhaxJBE8?t=1m29s)).

It means we indeed need wings to fly.

> But hey now,don't know girl we both know what to do. ([here](https://youtu.be/Y7yBhaxJBE8?t=29s))

Comment: Next time, try to add a time stamp or some kind of time reference when you refer to a video and specific lyrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are thinking that it's a double negative(?)

> don't ... no ...

actually in this case it means wings are not necessary.
It's the same as

> we don't need nothing
>   *we don't need anything*
>
> Wings are not necessary *(to fly)*
>   As long as you love me *(I can fly without having wings)*

Maybe because it's a love song?

In the video, the words in your second sentence were changed to

> But hey now, don't know girl, we both know it's a cruel world.

Comment: Small typo, second to last line, "your". Also, I think you are trying to say that the actual lyrics say "you know, girl, we both know" and this makes (more) sense than the incorrect written lyrics.